# VSCode not building latest code from docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have a scenario where I have installed a python project on docker (ubuntu) and I have attached VSCode to the running container so it allows me to edit my code reactJS code in my windows environment. Any change I made in reactjs I would run `yarn build` on the virtual environment and the changes would be displayed.

Recently I have noticed that this has all changed. VSCode is serving up
code from the initial git (and I honestly have no idea where it's coming from).

If I make a change in VSCode and I look at the file in docker the change is reflected, However, if I run yard build and browse to the link, the change isnt shown there.

What's more is that this method used to work and just suddenly, I could not make any change and all the changes I had already done was reversed. This has lead me to believe for some reason the application is serving what I downloaded from git but i'm not sure how to fix this.

Appreciate any assistance.

Regards

> {
>
> ```
> "version": "0.2.0",
> "configurations": [
>     {
>         "type": "pwa-node",
>         "request": "launch",
>         "name": "Launch Program",
>         "skipFiles": [
>             "<node_internals>/**"
>         ],
>         "program": "${file}"
>     }
> ] }
> ```

Package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf build/* && parcel build -d build src/index.html",
    "surge": "cd build && cp index.html 200.html && surge . lofcrypto.surge.sh",
    "build:nominify": "NODE_ENV=development parcel build --no-minify --public-url /static/ src/index.html",
    "dev": "ENVIRONMENT=dev parcel --port 32955 src/index.html",
    "i18next": "i18next src/**/*.tsx -c i18next-parser.config.js",
    "generate": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sumsub/websdk": "^1.1.0",
    "await-timeout": "^1.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.3.0",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "defer-promise": "^2.0.1",
    "graphql": "^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "inversify": "^5.0.1",
    "inversify-react": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "luxon": "^1.25.0",
    "mobx": "^6.1.4",
    "mobx-react": "^7.1.0",
    "mobx-react-router": "^4.1.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "oaf-react-router": "^2.1.1",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "react": ">= 16.8.0",
    "react-click-away-listener": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.4",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-toastify": "^8.0.2",
    "src": "^1.1.2",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "swiper": "^6.7.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "urql": "^2.0.3",
    "web3": "^1.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.12.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "1.21.5",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.22.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-graphql-request": "^3.2.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.18.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-urql": "^2.0.7",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.11",
    "@types/defer-promise": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
    "@types/luxon": "^1.25.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.9",
    "@types/numeral": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dropzone": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.2",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/store": "^2.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "^1.3.4",
    "ethereum-abi-types-generator": "^1.1.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "vite": "^2.3.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer this question without more details about your setup. 
Can you minimally include your .vscode/launch.json, package.json? Additional Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml could also be relevant, but optional

Comment: @PhilippeHebert I dont have all those docker files, I just downloaded an image / container via the gui, then I installed my application from git. Then form vscode I attached to a running container and pointed to the folder my code was in

Comment: But surely if you've configured VSCode to attach to a container you should have a launch.json? See link here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Comment: @PhilippeHebert Added default launch.json to main question

Comment: Thanks! Not sure it's of any help. Can you add your package.json as well, a screenshot of your folder structure, the name:version of the Dockerfile you pull from as well as the command you use to run your container, and the name of the command you use in VSCode to connect to said configuration (is it "pwa-node"?)?

Comment: Just as a tip for your questions moving forward - it's better if you demonstrate proof of work (that you've investigated the thing), and it's even better if you put all the necessary (minimal) configuration/code to reproduce or give a good idea of what the issue is. Too much info will deter people from answering, too little and you won't get an answer either (and you'll get downvoted) ;)

Comment: @PhilippeHebert I don't really have all these config files. I installed docker, pulled a node from hub.docker and then added a container. I then pulled git in the container. I then moved to VS code, installed the remote container extension and attached it to a running container to access my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237910/discussion-between-niana-and-philippe-hebert).